# SQL Server 2014 DELETE with OUTPUT

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Why would I get an 'incorrect syntax' error with this (on the OUTPUT keyword):

```
DELETE tb
    FROM dbo.TransactionBatch tb
    OUTPUT Deleted.TransactionID INTO #TransactionIDs
    INNER JOIN @BatchTransactionIDs tid 
        ON tb.TransactionID = tid.TransactionID
```

@BatchTransactionIDs is a User-Defined Table type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `OUTPUT` has to go before the `FROM`.

```
DELETE tb
    OUTPUT Deleted.TransactionID INTO #TransactionIDs
    FROM dbo.TransactionBatch tb
    INNER JOIN @BatchTransactionIDs tid 
        ON tb.TransactionID = tid.TransactionID
```

Answer (score 0):

The `OUTPUT` clause belongs before the `FROM` clause.
See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/delete-transact-sql